# How to pass "&" Symbol in json API

Tags: android, json

How to pass the "&" symbol in json format.

Input is here,

json:

```
{
    "sid":"sid2",
    "password":"a&b",
    "sec_type":"2"
}
```

In this while i am forming `json`, password field 'a&b' is automatically converted into '\u0026' before sending. It takes me into a issue.

I converted the model using tojson() method.

Comment: No it wont:( Please look on it https://imgur.com/q1rYgu5

Comment: Which JSON library are you using ?

Comment: try this String response = URLEncoder.encode(value,"UTF-8");

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Gson` , then

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
gson.toJson(yourObject);
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by below format. Thanks all..:)

```
JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObject.put("ssid", getID());
    jsonObject.put("password", a&b());
    jsonObject.put("sec_type", getSecType());
    return jsonObject.toString();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "";
}
```

Now it clearly going exactly what i sent